# Notation for standardized random variable?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, gamma-distribution, notation

I am wondering if there is in use a notation for a standardized random variable? If $X$ is a random variable following some parametric distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$, then if there is a notation for the standardized random variable $\sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)$?

Comment: The standard normal distribution N(0,1) has a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution Is that what you are asking or do you want every possible distribution to be standardized?

Comment: @Carl, Yes, not specifically for normal.

Answer (score 1):

The standard normal distribution assumptions aren't exactly maintained for standardizing other distributions. For example, the normal distribution is
$$f(x \; | \; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} } \; e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }\;.$$

The standard normal distribution is a special case when mean $\mu=0$ and standand deviation $\sigma =1$, and it is described by its standard probability density function,
$$\varphi(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{- \frac 12 x^2}
\;.$$

The formula for the [probability density function of one method of generalizing the gamma distribution](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366b.htm) is 
$$f(x) = \frac{(\frac{x-\mu}{\beta})^{\gamma - 1}\exp{(-\frac{x-\mu}
{\beta}})} {\beta\Gamma(\gamma)}  \hspace{.2in}  x \ge \mu; \;\gamma,
\beta > 0\;.$$

The case where $\mu=0$ and $\beta=1$ is called the standard gamma distribution. The equation for the standard gamma distribution reduces to

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{\gamma - 1}e^{-x}} {\Gamma(\gamma)}  \hspace{.2in}
x \ge 0; \gamma > 0\;,$$

where the mean is $\gamma$ and the variance is also $\gamma$. So, the mean is not set to be zero. Nor can it be, unlike for the symmetric normal distribution, we cannot define a gamma distribution to be $-\infty<X<\infty$. In the standard  case, the gamma distribution is zero for $X<0$. In other words, the [support is semi-infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals,_usually_[0,%E2%88%9E).

Generalizing from these two distributions, we can write standard forms for distributions, but the rules for what a standard distribution is vary according to the nature of the distribution itself.